# Error in crossprod(x, y) : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Tags: r

I am using GWASpoly for my GWAS studies Analysis. Among all the data I have performed with the same code and got the results but for one parameter the Error as mentioned in the Subject is coming. I have tried to overcome this with different methods but all went useless.

> First Error is: Error in crossprod(x, y) :    requires numeric/complex
>   matrix/vector arguments and the Second one that i am getting is :
>   Error: is. element (paramas$fixed, colnammes (data@fixed) are not all
>   TRUE.

I am using the following code:

```
data3 <- GWASpoly(data2,models=c("general","additive","1-dom","2-dom"),traits=c("ATS"), params=params)
```

For all other parameters it works well but for ATS it's showing ERROR as mentioned in the subject.

Comment: Impossible to say for sure given you haven't shown any code.

Comment: No i have used the same thing for all other parameters. in between the single file this parameter also exists but specially for this i am getting the error that is mention firstly.'

Comment: Error in crossprod(x, y) : requires numeric/complex matrix/vector arguments

Comment: here is the code that i am using

Comment: data3 <- GWASpoly(data2,models=c("general","additive","1-
dom","2-dom"),traits=c("ATS"),
params=params)

Comment: Please post your code in the question, not in the comments.  [mcve]